# Get ManagedBeans in Custom JSF Validator dynamically

Tags: jsf, validation

I want to validate values dynamically by using a custom validator that I can be used with several components. The custom validator gets those values from different ManagedBeans depending on its usage.

How to determine which ManagedBean the value is retrieved from? So I can get it, validate it, and put it back into a ManagedBean.

My Custom Validator:

```
@FacesValidator(value = "valid")
public class DateValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
             Object value) throws ValidatorException {
       // Bean bean = ?
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really odd use case for a `Validator`. Don't you *actually* need a `Converter`? A `Validator` shouldn't manipulate/convert data, but just check/validate data and untouch it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the description. I will not manipulate the data in the validator. I just want to get the ManagedBean, in which the submitted Value of the component later will be saved, because in this Bean there is some Data I need for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that is good approach as in validation phase model is still not updated, what you are getting is just input value from view. I wonder why you need bean instance there. If your validation depends on other component in view you can refer [link @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751509/jsf-validate-value-provided-in-both-fields-or-none-of-them) and [Validator for multiple fields](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html).

As you refer you need to validate it and put back, thats why validation phase is all about, validate it in your validator and if it fails it will not be passed to managed bean.

Have a look at this link for JSF lifecycle [JSF Lifecycle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/)

Hope this helps !!!